# SQL query that will give me billing address for each account, but home address if there is no billing

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's a simplified example of my data:

```
    Acct  AddType   Address
    ====  =======   ============
    1001  Home      1239 Maple
    1001  Billing   456 Broadway
    1002  Billing   1234 Main
    1003  Home      1278 Walnut
```

I'm trying to create a SQL query that will give me one address for each account.  It should be the billing address for each account, but if there isn't a billing address, then I want home address.

something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
WHERE 
  (COUNT(Acct) > 1 AND AddType = 'Billing') OR 
  (COUNT(Acct) = 1 AND AddType = 'Home')
```

which should return:

```
    Acct  AddType   Address
    ====  =======   ============
    1001  Billing   456 Broadway
    1002  Billing   1234 Main
    1003  Home      1278 Walnut
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple (and efficient) way to do this is to use `union all` and some additional logic:

```
select t.*
from table1 t
where addtype = 'Billing'
union all
select t.*
from table1 t
where addtype = 'Home' and
      not exists (select 1 from table1 t2 where t2.acct = t.acct and t2.addtype = 'Billing');
```

There are other methods.  This is typically the simplest for only two values.  A more general form is to use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by acct
                                order by (case when addtype = 'Billing' then 1
                                               when addtype = 'Home' then 2
                                               else 3
                                          end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from table1 t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks!  My 'Table1' is actually the results of a subquery.  Using your 2nd method seemed to be the better option and worked!

Comment: I realize now that there is a rare case where there is neither a 'Billing' or 'Home' address but there is a 'Mailing' address.  To accommodate for this case, I'd just add another `WHEN` line to the `CASE`?

Comment: @WesLarson . . . For the second method, you don't have to do anything (as long as there is an `else` clause).  Of course, you can add an additional `when` as well to be explicit.

Answer (score 1):

I've used self joins for things like this:

```
SELECT 
  Acct,
  case
    when c.Address IS NOT NULL then c.Address
    else b.Address
  end as Address,
  *
FROM 
  Table1 a LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 b ON a.Acct = b.Acct
    AND b.AddType = 'Home'
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 c ON a.Acct = c.Acct
    AND c.AddType = 'Billing'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just offering another option:

```
SELECT a.[Acct]
    ,a.[AddType]
    ,a.[Address]
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY [Acct]
                            ORDER BY [AddType] ASC
                          ) AS [Row_Num]
     FROM Table1
     ) AS a
WHERE a.[Row_num] = 1
```